# Transparent search for a std::map with a std::pair as a key

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

If there is a `std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, some_type>` what is the best way to find its values?

I guess the most obvious one is to do something like this:
`map.find(std::make_pair(str1, str2));`
but this will lead to a copy-construction of the `str1` and `str2` strings during the pair construction.

I hoped that maybe `map.find(std::make_pair(std::ref(str1), std::ref(str2)));` could help, but unfortunately no, this still produces string copies.

`map.find(std::make_pair(std::move(str1), std::move(str2))` should work but let's assume that these strings (`str1`, `str2`) are const or should not be moved.

So I'm asking whether there is any other way to do a the map search without making redundant string copies?

(Note that using `std::string_view` for the `std::map key` is NOT an option since the map should own its strings.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

C++14 added the following overload for [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) which allows transparent search:

```cpp
template< class K >
const_iterator find( const K& x ) const;
```

To make use of this, you still need the `std::map` to have a suitable comparator:

```cpp
struct pair_less {
    // important for transparent comparison, see std::map:find documentation
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    template <typename T, typename U>
      requires pair_less_than_comparable<T, U> // C++20, see below
    bool operator()(const T& a, const U& b) const {
        if (a.first < b.first) return true;
        if (b.first < a.first) return false;
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int, pair_less> m { /* ... */ };
    // ...
    std::string a = "a", b = "b";
    // now works and creates no copies
    auto pos = m.find(std::make_pair(std::ref(a), std::ref(b)));
}
```

This `pair_less` is totally transparent.
It can directly compare `std::pair<X, Y>` to `std::pair<const X&, const Y&>`.

#### Note on `std::pair::operator<`

The C++ standard requires [`std::pair::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) to be transparent since [LWG Defect 3865](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3865).
Theoretically, this would make `std::less<void>` or `std::ranges::less` sufficient as a transparent comparator.

[However, libstdc++ does not yet implement transparent `std::pair` comparisons](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/ed5bf2080c538b63459891dbd8f217823f7c6127/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_pair.h#L840-L844) at the time of writing, so `std::less<void>` would only work for compilers other than GCC.

#### Proper C++20 constraints

Properly constraining the call operator of `pair_less` is not so easy.
It's not strictly necessary anyway, but moves the error to the call site of the operator and may be better for diagnostics.

The usual approach would be something along the lines of

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
concept pair_less_than_comparable
  = requires (const T& t, const U& u) {
      { t.first < u.first } -> /* boolean-testable */;
      { t.second < u.second } -> /* boolean-testable */;
  }
```

See also [`boolean-testable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/boolean-testable).

Comment: Although it looks like that ```using is_transparent = std::true_type;``` is also needed to be added to the ```pair_less``` comparator. Otherwise I see that std string copies are still created. But everything is OK when ```is_transparent``` is added

Answer (score 12):

To avoid key construction, you can use `std::map` with a transparent comparator. In many cases you don't need to implement your own one - the standard provides [`std::less<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) that does the job.

Unfortunately, it won't work with `std::pair` keys because `std::pair` [lacks heterogeneous comparisons](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3865): you can't compare `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` to `std::pair<const std::string&, const std::string&>`.

But if you could change `std::pair` to `std::tuple`,  it will work:

```
std::map<std::tuple<std::string, std::string>, int, std::less<>> map;
// ...
auto pos = map.find(std::make_tuple(std::cref(str1), std::cref(str2)));
```

Comment: @Voivoid And when the standard is fixed, you'll be able to use `std::pair` again. ;)

Comment: Since https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3865, `std::pair` comparisons are required to be transparent. GCC just doesn't implement this yet. `std::less<void>` might work in GCC 15.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you can't have `std::string_view` keys, you can still use `std::string_view` for your comparator (since you can easily convert a `std::string` -> `std::string_view`):

```cpp
struct string_pair_comparator {
    constexpr bool operator()(std::tuple<std::string_view, std::string_view> l, std::tuple<std::string_view, std::string_view> r) const noexcept {
#ifdef __cpp_lib_three_way_comparison
        auto cmp = l <=> r;
#else
        auto cmp = std::get<0>(l).compare(std::get<0>(r));
        if (cmp == 0) cmp = std::get<1>(l).compare(std::get<1>(r));
#endif
        return cmp < 0;
    }

    using is_transparent = void;
};

std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, some_type, string_pair_comparator> map;
```

`std::tuple` was used instead of `std::pair` because you can convert `pair` -> `tuple`, but not the reverse. This means you can use tuple keys as well, which have handy factory functions:

```cpp
map.find(std::tie(str1, str2))
map.find(std::forward_as_tuple(str1, str2))
// pairs also still work
map.find(std::make_pair(std::ref(str1), std::ref(str2)))
```

Two `compare`s were used instead of `l < r` because the pre-C++20 tuple's `operator<` would result in three `memcmp`s instead of two (`l[0] < r[0]; r[0] < l[0]; l[1] < r[1]`. These do not seem to be optimized out).